# ImportError: the 'trace' from 'tensorflow.python.profiler'

Tags: python, tensorflow, pycharm, environment, anaconda3

I were using environments for months and they were working perfectly.. suddenly i can not execute any code in pycharm under any virtual environment and i get this error massage:

from tensorflow.python.profiler import trace
ImportError: cannot import name 'trace' from 'tensorflow.python.profiler' (C:\Users\Nuha\anaconda3\envs\tf_1.15\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\profiler_*init*_.py)

Any help please!!
It seams that it happens because i install more packages and maybe conflict occurs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it was because environment conflict so i rebuild new environment and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

Try to install trace

```
pip3 install trace
```

Comment: I tried on the env but get this error :  ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement trace (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for trace

Comment: while searching i found this => https://pypi.org/project/traces/ Try install it

Comment: I installed it but still same error